# Bootstrap multiple progress bars start meddle

Tags: progress-bar, bootstrap-5

[image: pic1]

[image]

I want to create a progress bar using Bootstrap that looks like the image below (related to the stock market price). There is a middle point (starting price). The lowest price and the highest price are used for the Progress Bar. If each of these two prices is smaller than the starting price, it will be red and if it is bigger than the starting price, it will be green. It is also possible that both prices are greater than the starting price and vice versa.
[image: pic2]
How can I do that? Or where exactly should I research?

**update**

```css
.progress-label.left {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.progress-label.right {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 1em;
}



.price-change {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;


}

.price-change .left,
.price-change .right {
  flex: 0 0 3%;
  font-size: .75rem;
}

.price-change .left {
  text-align: left;
}

.price-change .progress {
  margin: 0.25rem;
  flex-grow: 8;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="fa-IR">
  <body>
  <div class="main-content">
      <div class="page-content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="price-change mb-3">
      <span class="text-muted right ms-2">210500</span>
      <div class="progress" style="height:6px;">
        <div class="progress-bar bg-transparent" role="progressbar" style="width: 20%"></div>
        <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 80%"></div>
        <div class="progress-bar bg-transparent" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%">
        </div>
        <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 20%"></div>
        <div class="progress-bar bg-transparent" role="progressbar" style="width: 80%">
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="text-muted left me-2">210000</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Using Bootstrap I partially built this. But I have to do a lot of calculations to replace progress-bar percentages.
[image]
How can I specify the two arrows as well as the middle of it as shown in the figure?

Comment: What you are looking for is a slider, not a progress bar. https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b4/jquery/plugins/multi-range/

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question is too broad.

Comment: I updated the post and it was easily implemented with Progress-bar.